# Associated typescript model goes away when data is passed to other page

Tags: angular, typescript, model

I have create a typescript model in angular application. Initialized an object with that model. I am passing the object through routing, but on 2nd component (i.e. UserComponent) the associated types is not avialbe (highlighted in image). Below are the code snippets. Stackblitz url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/tsmodel-test

Model

```
export class UserModel{
  name: string;
  id: number;
}
```

1st Component

```
export class HelloComponent  { 
  user = new UserModel(); 

  constructor(private router: Router){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user.name = 'abdc';
    this.user.id = 23232
    console.log(this.user)
  }

  btnClick() {
    this.router.navigate(['user'], { state: {data: this.user} });
  }
}
```

2nd Component

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  user;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Component2')
    console.log(history.state.data);
    this.user = history.state.data;
  }
}
```

Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Use typecasting..

Comment: Type assertion doesn't help it is only for compile time. I tried with 'object as SomeModel'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `history.state.data` type is any. It cannot hold a specific data type since its arbitory. If you want to access the data as a `UserModel` type, then do the following in your user.component.ts file

```js
 user: UserModel = new UserModel();
 ngOnInit() {
    this.user = history.state.data;
  }
```

Note: *data passing between components can be done in better ways than passing in the state data*

**Update**

```js
user: UserModel = new UserModel();
  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = Object.assign(new UserModel, history.state.data);
    console.log(this.user);
  }
```

Comment: This is not working as type of data is any, and till this time the associated types have gotremoved.

Comment: You may set data type of usermodel from your helloComponent but history.state.data is an arbitrary type. Therefore, when you use it in second component you cant get that type. What i have done above in the answer will allow you to access the class properties even though it doesn't show in console.log. If you want grt it in console. Then map it to the class explicitly

Comment: Yes, It is works, but In some case in need to check instanceof UserModel, then it is failing.

Comment: @MdJunaidAlam I have editted the answer on how to map it to userModel. Hope that will work for you

Answer (score 0):

the console does not display the typescript type, but javascript class UserModel. After that, you are retrieving state of History object, I think it is a copy of the object (to be verified). It is not the right way to pass object between 2 components

Comment: I understand, But for the application I am working on, data is huge and I need to access on different routes.